# CSS/JAVASCRIPT rotation javascript issue

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, rotation

I have a big issue:

I must rotate a background image of a `<div id= "foo">...</div>` of an arbitrary number of degrees.

I have found this code to do that, but only in css:

```
#foo:before
{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Now I want to do the same in javascript dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot set a pseudo-element directly with javascript (the `:before` in your CSS rule is a pseudo-element, and doesn't match to any *real*, retrievable element in the DOM).

The only thing you *could* do is dynamically create a `<style>` element with the `#foo:before` rule and attach it to the DOM:

```
function rotate(){
    var rotation, sheet, cssText;

    // Randomly choose a rotation and create the cssText rule (webkit)
    rotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * (350 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
    cssText = '#foo::before {-webkit-transform:rotate('+rotation+'deg); }';

    // Since we're rotating a pseudo-element, we need to create a stylesheet
    // since :before's cannot be directly manipulated
    sheet = document.createElement('style');
    sheet.type = 'text/css';
    sheet.media = 'screen';
    if(sheet.styleSheet)
        sheet.styleSheet.cssText = cssText;
    else
        sheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssText));
    document.head.appendChild(sheet);
};
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/9S2tc/

Comment: My code doesn't work...
here is my code

http://pastebin.com/V4KNZuBL

Can you help me where is the issue?

Comment: Yeah, your CSS won't work. It's hard to see without a running example... but, first, you have to give your `#element:before` a `display:block` to work like a block element and make the `z-index` positive. Next, your `#element2` has an `overflow:hidden`, but then you position the `#element:before` outside  with a `top` and `left` of `-50%`. **This is all outside of your question that I've answered, though.** I've provided a working example, see the jsFiddle above.

Comment: Can you adjust my code because I haven't understand what I must do.
Sorry.

Comment: Sure, here's a jsFiddle with your working css/js/html: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/eh34u/ (Additionally, I added a click event to the `div` that will randomly rotate the image as well).

Comment: thank you, but I don't know why, but doesn't work another time....
this is what I have in mi html file, http://pastebin.com/DLu3nV5Q , please, can you give my code corrected in pastebin's page? thank you!

Comment: Sorry man, I've answered your question, provided you with working examples above and beyond what your question has asked, and even iterated your own code outside of your question to a working point for you. If you would like to contract me at an hourly rate, please contact me privately.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jquery, try using this small plugin that rotates image in a fantastic way.

[click here for documentation and example](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

Answer (score -1):

html. set background to 'someElementInside'and fill it to 100% of parent width and height

```
<div id="elem">
  <div id="someElementInside">
  </div>
<div>
```

css

```
  #elem{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  #someElementInside{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(image.png)
  }
```

jquery

```
<script>

    var rotator = function(youDegreesValue){

        $("#someElementInside").css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ youDegreesValue +'deg)',
                          '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ youDegreesValue +'deg)',
                          '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ youDegreesValue +'deg)',
                          'transform' : 'rotate('+ youDegreesValue +'deg)'});

    }



    $(document).ready(function(){


            $("#rotateButon").click(function(){

                rotator(120);   

            });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I must define before in the head? because doesn't work.

Comment: @Anth in html add `<span id="rotateButon"> rotate! </span>`. than you click on it, u will run function which rotate block. P.S. why in css you want rotate pseudo element 'before', and in question text you need rotate div directly?

Comment: I don't want rotate the div, but the background image inside it.
this is the code.

http://pastebin.com/vUAXWDwb

Please help me.

Comment: i write above - you can set background-image which you want in 'element2' to 'element2BG'. so element2 will be `background:none`, and element2BG will be `background-image`.... `<div id="element2"><div id="element2BG"></div><div>` visual effect will be same

Comment: @Anth http://pastebin.com/GJi8pSn5 and don't forget to add jquery in head  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: For me is so different because I must have the div stop, because I must turn the background image while an image in a tag <img> stay stop.

Comment: @Anth sorry my knowledge of English is not enough to understand your last comment

Comment: no problem. i try to do what you told me. but doesn't work. this is the code, http://pastebin.com/BE2puTtz where is the issue?

Comment: @Anth download jquery and connect it in head - for me its work <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> P.S. when connect you local file - delete this string <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I must run it without jquery because is an application where I can't install jquery in device destination

Comment: when you must use @rgthree answer -it's pure js